# Rock Paper Scissors Game Best 2 out of 3 Loop Issues

Tags: java, loops

How do I make the computer automatically win when the wrong input (something aside from the options; rock, paper, scissors) is entered? It need these to be counted as well. Also, when the players chooses to play again, how can I remove "Welcome..." from reappearing; It is only needed when program first starts.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
/**
 * 
 * @author Chloe Harris
 *
 */
public class RockPaperScissorsGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        //Set integers for wins, losses, rounds, and user
        while(true){
            int wins = 0;
            int losses = 0;
            int round = 0;
            int Player = 0;

            //Plays 3 rounds before terminating
            //Prompt user to input Rock Paper Scissors
            System.out.print("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors! Best 2 out of 3! \n");

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
            while(round<3) {
                System.out.println("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\" or \"Scissors\"");
                Random Game = new Random();
                int Computer = 1+Game.nextInt(3);

                int Scissors, Rock, Paper;
                Rock = 1;
                Paper = 2;
                Scissors= 3;

                String UserInput =  keyboard.next();
                if(UserInput.equals("Rock"))  {
                    Player = 1;
                }
                if(UserInput.equals("Paper")) {
                    Player = 2;
                }
                if(UserInput.equals("Scissors")) {
                    Player = 3;
                }

                //If the user enters a value greater then 3 (Scissors) or less than 1 (Rock)
                //it will terminate the program and display an error message
                while (Player > 3 || Player < 1) {
                    losses++;
                    round++;
                    System.out.println("Not a valid input! Computer wins");
                    System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");

                }

                //Establish tie scenarios using if statements
                if(Player == Computer){
                    if(Player == Scissors){
                        System.out.println("Scissors v Scissors! Tie!");
                        round++;
                    }
                    if(Player == Rock){
                        System.out.println("Rock v Rock! Tie!");
                        round++;
                    }
                    if(Player == Paper){
                        System.out.println("Paper v Paper! Tie!");
                        round++;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");

                }

                //Establish the various winning scenarios using if and else if statements
                //Player wins
                if(Player == Scissors)
                    if(Computer == Paper){
                        System.out.println("Scissors v Paper! Player Wins!");
                        wins++;
                        round++;
                        System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");
                    }
                //Computer wins
                    else if(Computer == Rock){
                        System.out.println("Scissors v Rock! Computer Wins!");
                        losses++;
                        round++;
                        System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");
                    }
                //Player wins
                if(Player == Rock)
                    if(Computer == Scissors ){
                        System.out.println("Rock v Scissors! Player Wins!");
                        wins++;
                        round++;
                        System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");
                    }   
                //Computer wins
                    else if (Computer == Paper){
                        System.out.println("Rock v Paper! Computer Wins!");
                        losses++;
                        round++;
                        System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");
                    }
                //Player Wins
                if(Player == Paper)
                    if(Computer == Rock){
                        System.out.println("Paper v Rock! Player Wins!");
                        wins++;
                        round++;
                        System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");

                    }
                //Computer Wins 
                    else if (Computer == Scissors){
                        System.out.println("Paper v Scissors! Computer Wins!");
                        losses++;
                        round++;
                        System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");
                    }
            }

            //Determine final winner using if statements
            //Ask if player would like to play again by setting up string 
            if(wins>losses){
                System.out.println("The Player Wins!");
            }if(losses>wins){
                System.out.println("The Computer Wins!");
            }
            System.out.println("Play again? \"Yes\" or \"No\"");
            Scanner YesNo = new Scanner(System.in);

            String YesNo_String = YesNo.next();
            if(YesNo_String.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))    {
            }if(YesNo_String.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))    {
                System.out.println ("Goodbye!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, do you know we can determine who is the winner with only 3 lines of code? I see that in order to determine who is the winner, you wrote 30 over line of codes.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just change your if statements to the following:

```
if(UserInput.equals("Rock"))  {
    Player = 1;
}
else if(UserInput.equals("Paper")) {
    Player = 2;
}
else if(UserInput.equals("Scissors")) {
    Player = 3;
}
else {
    Player = 0;
}
```

You already have it set up so that if player < 1, the computer wins automatically.

Note: your `while (Player > 3 || Player < 1)` statement should actually be an `if` statement. Otherwise, you'll have an infinite loop there.

To answer your second question, just move the statement `System.out.print("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors! Best 2 out of 3! \n");` above your loop. That way it will only be asked once: at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

For both the player entering in the wrong data and checking if they have already played, create Booleans and check those Booleans in an if/else statement.  Since this may or may not be homework I'll solve this for the "Welcome... " message.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Boolean firstPlay = true;

    //Set integers for wins, losses, rounds, and user
    while(true){
        int wins = 0;
        int losses = 0;
        int round = 0;
        int Player = 0;

        //Plays 3 rounds before terminating
        //Prompt user to input Rock Paper Scissors
        if(firstPlay) {
            System.out.print("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors! Best 2 out of 3! \n");
            firstPlay = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are setting the value of "Player" to either 1, 2, or 3 with the default being 0. I would say set it to the default value at the start of every loop, and if its 0 allow the computer to win. Or change your if satements to if-elseif. I'll provide an example below.

```
....
if(UserInput.equals("Rock"))  {
    Player = 1;    
} else if(UserInput.equals("Paper")) {
   Player = 2;
} else if(UserInput.equals("Scissors")) {
   Player = 3;
} else {
    Player = 0;
}
```

Since you already have a statement saying if Player < 1 or > 3 that the computer wins, you are set. Also your "Welcome" statement is inside of your while loop. Because of this every time it iterates through the loop you will see it. Try moving it outside of the loop.